# Codeigniter MY_Controller not sending variables to the view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter and tried making a  custom controller to extend all my controllers from. It will then pass it to a layout were all the code except for the main page will be. I hope someone can tell me what I am doing wrong. Below is how I have it set up and the code for each controller and view.

I made a `MY_Controller` so I could extend all my controllers from it. Inside of the `MY_Controller` I added a public function called `loadView`. Below is the code.

I then extended my `Contact` controller from it and called `loadView` and passed some variables. See the code below as well.

In my layout/main view it will not see any variables. Below is a snippet for seeing the title.

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
//    protected $trainedJobs = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function loadView($layout = "main", $title = "What Do I Work", $page = "index", $xtraCSS = null, $xtraJS = null, $hideNavbar = false)
    {

        $data['$_title'] = $title;
        $data['$_view'] = $page;
        $data['$_xtraCSS'] = $xtraCSS;
        $data['$_xtraJS'] = $xtraJS;
        $data['$_hideNavbar'] = $hideNavbar;

        $this->load->view('layouts/' . $layout, $data);
    }
}
```

**My Contact Controller**

```
class Contact extends MY_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {

        $this->loadView('main',"Contact Us", 'contact', 'base_url("assets/css/contact-us.css")');
    }

}
```

**Inside my main layout view**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title><?php if (isset($_title)) echo $_title; ?></title>
</head>
<body>

<?php if (isset($_view) && $_view)
$this->load->view($_view);
?>

</body></html>
```

Comment: Noticed that you are having `4 parameters` on your Contract Controller, and on your Custom Controller, it has `6 parameters`. It is obviously to have an error then.

Comment: @Roshan all `loadView()` parameters are optional, so you can call it with anything from 0-6 parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the variable names you're using, for example:

```
$data['$_title'] = $title;
```

The array key (`$_title`) will become the variable name in the view.  But there's no way to address a variable name which starts with a `$`, in fact that's not a legal variable name AFAICT.  [According to the PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php) a variable name:

> ... starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores.

No mention of `$` being a legal character at all - and it definitely can't be the first character.

I was curious and tested, but `$$_title` doesn't work, neither does `${$_title}` (that syntax works for [variable-variables, which are perfectly legal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)).

AFAICT you are not trying to use variable-variables, so I think this is a simple typo, and all you need to do is remove those `$`s from your array keys:

```
$data['_title']      = $title;
$data['_view']       = $page;
$data['_xtraCSS']    = $xtraCSS;
$data['_xtraJS']     = $xtraJS;
$data['_hideNavbar'] = $hideNavbar;
```

Comment: Yes, Thank You! I not know how I missed it.

Answer (score 0):

As rightly suggested by Dont_panic do not use `$` in key

Also Passing so many parameters will always cause this kind of problems, you have to remember their sequence and pass them accordingly.

If you want to load CSS and JS files dynamically for each page which will require it to run. Use a database to fetch page files in an array you require and use it by `foreach($file['css'] as $key => $value)` and `foreach($file['js'] as $key => $value)` or create an array in the model and return.

Example

```
public function get_contact_files() {
$params['css'] = array(
0 => 'assets/css/file_1.css',
1 => 'assets/css/file_2.css',
2 => 'assets/css/file_3.css',
);
$params['js'] = array(
0 => 'assets/js/file_1.js',
1 => 'assets/js/file_2.js',
2 => 'assets/js/file_3.js',
);

return $params;
}
```

In controller

```
$data['common'] = array(
        'page_title' => 'My Page Title',
        'page_heading' => 'My Page Heading'
);
$this->load->model('File_model');
$data['file'] = $this->File_model->get_contact_files();
```

In view

```
<html>
        <head>
                <title><?php echo $common['page_title']; ?></title>
<?php foreach($file['css'] as $key => $value) { ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url($value); ?>">
<?php } ?>
        </head>
        <body>
        <h1><?php echo $common['page_heading']; ?></h1>
<?php foreach($file['js'] as $key => $value) { ?>
<script src="<?php echo base_url($value); ?>"></script>
<?php } ?>
        </body>
</html>
```

**Suggestion 1:** There is an inbuilt template library in case you want to use

In controller

```
$this->load->library('parser');

$data = array(
        'page_title' => 'My Page Title',
        'page_heading' => 'My Page Heading'
);

$this->parser->parse('ur_page_view', $data);
```

In your view

```
<html>
        <head>
                <title>{page_title}</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <h1>{page_heading}</h1>
        </body>
</html>
```

**Suggestion 2:** If you want to pass the same variable in all function in that particular controller, use

```
<?php

class Page extends CI_Controller{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $data['page_title'] = 'My Page Title';
        $data['page_heading'] = 'My Page Heading';
        $this->load->vars($data);       
    }

    function name()
    {
        $this->load->view('ur_page_view',$data);
    }
```

In view

```
<html>
        <head>
                <title><?php echo $page_title; ?></title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <h1><?php echo $page_heading; ?></h1>
        </body>
</html>
```

> Please vote if this was helpful